# Javascript, how to set/call the value inside HTML output

Tags: javascript

**I did not the put the full code, it's a lot**

I have the a countingdown script,
Im trying to set a new string inside of this code, and then, call the same string to fill up a link inside html code.

**Code**

```
var events = [
      ["Example",["02:00","06:00","10:00","14:00","18:00","22:00"]], 
      ["Example2",["03:00","05:00","8:00","11:00","15:00","19:00"]],
```

Im trying to apply a different image name for each row that I have, I tried something like this:

**I tried this:**

```
 var events = [
    ["Example",["02:00","06:00","10:00","14:00","18:00","22:00"],["image.png"]],
    ["Example",["03:00","05:00","8:00","11:00","15:00","19:00"],["another-image.png"]],
```

**My HTML output is like that:**

```
<a href="#">' + line[0] + '<img src="https://mywebsite.com/images/'PRINT IMAGE.PNG HERE"></img>
```

I want to complete the link (example 3) with the value added (example 2)
How can I call it properly?
I cannot just fill the html with this name, cuz I need one different image for each row inside "var events".

[Check this Image please, question explained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed8CX.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I can not understand. Could you provide more information? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, thanks, In the second example, I added ['image.png'], how can I call it inside of a html code. to print out the string and complete my link to the image.

Comment: If you need different images for each row, why is there only one image name in the array?

Comment: Because I put only enough code to make the question. I'll apply the same for another rows.

Comment: and I'm confused what the nested array of timestamps is for.

Comment: Is for a countingdown script that show different times of different events, that need different images.

Comment: If I understand correctly, would it make more sense to have an array of objects instead of a thrice nested array?

 Are you trying to accomplish something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125489/using-vanilla-js-loop-through-an-array-of-objects-with-an-array-as-a-prop-using

Comment: Yeah, It would be a choice, but I have 26 arrays, Will be a lot of code, Can add a string inside that array? and then call it to print out afterwards?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qun2dd - check this image please, may you can understand. Sorry if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about parameters, every time you call the same funcion you want it to initiate but with different ids(show a different image), is that what you want? correct me to help you.

Comment: I have all them initiated already,
I cannot put the full code there, it's a lot.
I just dont know how to call the new ["image.png"] inside a HTML link to be completed.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qun2dd please, check this image. than you for your help